# Using Go packages

Tags: import, go, package

I am not sure how Go packages are invoked. For example if I want to create random numbers I should import `"math/random"`, but isn't it simply a part of the `"math"` library? So why doesn't this piece of code work:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main(){
    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(99))
    fmt.Println(r)

}
```

I mean, can't I just directly access the random functions by simply importing a superclass (in this case, simply the math `"math"` package)?

Comment: Go has neither classes nor superclasses. Packages have simple names, a name of "math/rand" does not imply that there *is* a package "math" or that (if so) there is *any* relation between them. Of course the standard library is organized in a sensible way, but package names and folders are just that, names and folders without any other structural cohension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thats because `rand` is a separate package that is hierarchically under the `math` package `math/rand`, so you have to import it specifically:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func main(){
    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(99))
    fmt.Println(r)

}
```